# Facebook not giving useful information in webhook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-webhooks

I have implemented Facebook webhook successfully by https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/

I have subscribed to But it is missing useful information, It gives me following response

The JSON is for example:

```
{
    "object":"user",
    "entry":[{
             "uid":"1408932149",
             "id":"1408932149",
             "time":1370253930,
             "changed_fields":["feed"]
   }]
}
```

But I want to track what actions happen on user's post which posted by my application. Here on every action it gives me **feed** in **changed_fields**. Its pretty useless for me

Basically I want to track like, comment and share of the posts for users in real time which shared from my software/app. I have subscribed to this reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/user/

I know for page it is working through webhook but how can I track user's post data with the webhook?

Can anyone suggest where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Facebook is telling you "user 1408932149's feed just changed". It's up to you to request their /me/feed with a valid access token to fetch their feed.

Comment: Then I have to make another graph API call. I have to make n numbers of API call. Isn't is possible that FB gives me actions from webhook without calling extra graph API

Comment: Yes, you have to make Graph API calls. That's the way the webhooks work. No way around it.

Comment: @ceejayoz It gives me a user id in webhook response then it will be really long path to track particular post actions like comment and like. Calling /me/feed will not work here. Isn't there any work-around FB gives me post id on which action occurs so I can call post graph API and track changes?

Comment: Question: are you getting `shared post` data in your webhook? I get new posts, reactions and comments in my webhook but not when a user shares a post. I can only get them using a manual call to `'/sharedposts` endpoint